# number of independent solutions to a set of second order PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

For an ODE like
$$
f''(x) + p(x)f'(x) + q(x)f(x) = 0\ ,
$$
one expects two linear independent solutions.

Now consider a system of second order linear PDEs, like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_x^2 f(x, y)\\
    \partial_x\partial_y f(x, y)\\
    \partial_y^2 f(x, y)
\end{pmatrix}
= P(x, y) \begin{pmatrix}
    f(x, y)\\
    \partial_x f(x, y)\\
    \partial_y f(x, y)\\
\end{pmatrix} \ ,
$$
where $P(x,y)$ is a matrix of rational functions of $x, y$, and suppose we are looking for solutions of $f(x,y)$ in $x, y$-series. Is there a way to see how many linear independent solutions there are?

Is it possible to generalize to $n$-variate function $f$ where all its second order derivatives $\partial_i \partial_j f$ are determined linearly (with rational function of $x_1, ..., x_n$ as coefficients) by $\partial_i f$ and $f$?